# Creating formula in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Maybe some of you could help me with creation of formula in sql. I need to perform calculations of the result of the expression for all given formulas. The notation of the formula is simple: P (X) means that the expression appends the integer X in parentheses. M (Y) means that the expression subtracts the integer Y in parentheses. The “+” symbol combines elements of the formula.
Example. given formula: `P (10) + M (5) + M (3) + P (1)`. It translates to `10-5-3 + 1 = 3`.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You want a formula *parser* in SQL? Something that can interpret the textual value `'P(10) + M(5) + M(3) + P(1)'` and yield numeric result `3`?

Comment: Write a stored function. How this would look like depends on your database

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: So you created a over-complicated syntax for storing constants. Why? Why not just store the result of the computation once and never have to do the computation when you need that value?

Answer (score 2):

Those easy formulas can be done in Microsoft SQL Server.

1. Split the formula in the different parts with [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and `+` as separator.
2. Use [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) to apply a negative number sign: `P(X) --> X` and `M(X) --> -X`.
3. Use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to turn the string parts into numbers.
4. Add everything up with a [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) aggregation and `group by` clause.

**Sample data**

```
create table input
(
  formula nvarchar(50)
);

insert into input (formula) values
('P(10)+M(5)+M(3)+P(1)'),
('P(7)+M(3)+M(4)');
```

**Solution**

```
select i.formula,
       sum(convert(int, replace(replace(replace(s.value,'P(', ''),'M(','-'),')',''))) as rez
from input i
cross apply string_split(i.formula, '+') s
group by i.formula;
```

**Result**

```
formula               rez
--------------------  ---
P(10)+M(5)+M(3)+P(1)    3
P(7)+M(3)+M(4)          0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3331f09b135c839674f299601e4f5a19) to see everything in action with intermediate steps.

Comment: Aside: Although [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't guarantee the order of the results ("The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.") that doesn't affect this solution since the only operator in the input is addition (`+`) and the corresponding aggregate `sum` is used.